# How to trigger a Azure devops pipeline whenever there is azure keyvault secret change?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, az

I'm trying to trigger an azure pipeline whenever there is new value-added to my secret or whenever there is a certificate change in the key vault.

Answer (score 1):

As @rickvdbosch wrote you can use Event Grid. Events are strongly typed:

```
[
   {
      "id":"00eccf70-95a7-4e7c-8299-2eb17ee9ad64",
      "topic":"/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/sample-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/sample-kv",
      "subject":"newsecret",
      "eventType":"Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNewVersionCreated",
      "eventTime":"2019-07-25T01:08:33.1036736Z",
      "data":{
         "Id":"https://sample-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/newsecret/ee059b2bb5bc48398a53b168c6cdcb10",
         "vaultName":"sample-kv",
         "objectType":"Secret",
         "objectName ":"newsecret",
         "version":" ee059b2bb5bc48398a53b168c6cdcb10",
         "nbf":"1559081980",
         "exp":"1559082102"
      },
      "dataVersion":"1",
      "metadataVersion":"1"
   }
]
```

so you exactly knows what happened. Please check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault) for more details. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-tutorial) for instance you have an example of how to configure Event Grid and Azure Key Vault. For instance you can modify this to put call to [Azure DevOps rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to trigger a build.

```bsh
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: @Vineesha.C I'm glad to hear that. Can you consider marking my reply as answer and upvoting you if that really helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Events (powered by [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/)) for this.

Here are the supported events for Key Vaults:

[image: Key Vault events]

Comment: Seems, it is not possible to choose  a particular secret/certificate, I would like to trigger my script on particular secret/certifictace change

Comment: How about checking the event data and only processing the interesting one(s)? Let's think in solutions here 